# Correct Pattern for handling Service Layer results

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I've been using Spring and Java for a while to build microservices. I am concerned by the way I am currently handling service layer results which uses "business exception"

Controller

```
@RestController
public class PurchaseController {
  @Autowired
  private PurchaseService purchaseService;

  @PostMapping("/checkout")
  public ResponseEntity<?> checkout(@RequestBody CheckoutRequest body) {
    try {
      SomeDTO dto = purchaseService.doCheckout(body);

      return ResponseEntity.ok(dto);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedException e) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (CustomBusinessException e) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class PurchaseService {
  // ...

  public DTO doCheckout(CheckoutRequest request) {
    // this one calls another microservice
    if (!isUserValid(request.userId)) {
      // current handling of business rules violation (1)
      throw new UnauthorizedException("User not valid");
    }

    if (request.total < 10) {
      // current handling of business rules violation (2)
      throw new CustomBusinessException("Minimum checkout at 20 dollars");
    }

    // ... do actual checkout
    return new DTO(someDTOData);
  }
}
```

I was comfortable at using this "pattern" because **I do not need to "if" the business result in the controller level** to return the appropriate `HttpStatusCode`, but since I've found some articles saying that exception is expensive specifically in Java, I doubt what I was doing is good for the long run.

Is there another correct way to gracefully handles the business result layer?

Comment: I practice almost the same pattern the only difference is I throw the same wrapping custom exception with the right reason. Like PurchaseServiceException("...")

Comment: @SaurabhSingh this means you need to "if" the exception on the controller level when you want to return different HttpStatus code for different reason. right?

Comment: The cost of throwing an exception is trivial compared to the cost of processing an HTTP request.

Comment: @DioDeiva Not from Controller I let it reach to `@ControllerAdvice` and send a custom response with proper status code and message. There you can segregate in different methods instead of if else

Comment: @SaurabhSingh thankyou, it seems controller advice is currently the best pattern for the case. but instead of throwing generic BusinessException I should make appropriate exceptions for the business cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with ResponseEntity in Spring is that they are typed with the result object you want to return when the endpoint is called successfully, so you can't return another body different from the happy path one, that in your case would be SameDTO. One way to address this issue is to use ? as the type of the response entity, as you have done but it is not the most recommended way.

So the best way to do this is precisely to use exceptions when there is a situation when you can't return the expected object and you have to return another object or status code, but instead of using a try-catch in the controller you should use an exception handler (Controller Advice) https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring.

This controller advice would catch any exception thrown in your application and depending on the exception type it could return a different response class or status code without affecting the main controller. One example of how can be your controller advice would be:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {


  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleInternal(final RuntimeException ex) {
    return ResponseEntity
    .status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    .body(ex.getMessage());
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(UnauthorizedException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> identityClientException(UnauthorizedException e) {
    return ResponseEntity
    .status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    .body(e.getMessage());
}
@ExceptionHandler(CustomBusinessException.class)
      public ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> identityClientException(CustomBusinessException e) {
        return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
        .body(e.getMessage());
}
```

And your controller woulb be much more clean without exception handling logic:

```
@RestController
public class PurchaseController {
  @Autowired
  private PurchaseService purchaseService;

  @PostMapping("/checkout")
  public ResponseEntity<SomeDTO> checkout(@RequestBody CheckoutRequest body){
      SomeDTO dto = purchaseService.doCheckout(body);
      return ResponseEntity.ok(dto);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this feature from Spring, and implemented some too in my project. But this means I am still using exception under the hood right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think It would be bad in Java to throw exceptions when errors or unexpected behavior occurs, In addition to this I think is the only way to return an alternate response body and maintain the right typing in the response entity (without using ?)

Comment: so far, I think this is the best pattern for the case. thanks to everyone for commenting and helping